# How to style both visited and not visited links in context?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

The following

```
#navigation  li  a{
    :link, :visited {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
}
```

was not worked for me.

Below code works but contains duplication

```
#navigation  li  a:link {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

#navigation  li  a:visited {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a style to multiple selectors you can group them by using a comma to separate the selectors.

```
#navigation  li  a:link,
#navigation  li  a:visited {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard CSS does not support nesting elements like you have.  To do so you need to use something like [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

This would work for standard CSS however...

```
#navigation  li  a:link,
#navigation  li  a:visited {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```